# Having trouble expanding the width's of my input bar and aligning it the center

Tags: html, css, material-ui

Here is the class I'm using to keep everything in the center of the users screen.

```
    container: {
      display: "flex",
      position: "absolute",
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      height: "100%",
      width: "100%",
      alignItems: "center",
    }
```

I'm using box to increase the width of my input bar:

```
          <Box p={3} width="100%" className={classes.container}>
            <div className={classes.container}>{children}</div>
          </Box>
```

[image]

Now here is what happens when I increase

[image]

The input bar is not centered and moves to the right!

How would I go about extending my input bar and keeping everything centered?

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you are using flexbox, so delete `position: absolute, top: 0, left: 0,` and add `justify-content: center` to your `className`

```
container: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: 'center',
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%",
    alignItems: "center",
  }
```

Comment: @woof is this fruitable for you ?